# How to use MKLocationManager (a Private API) in iOS

Tags: iphone, iphone-privateapi

I need to call

```
[[MKLocationManager sharedLocationManager] _applyChinaLocationShift:newLocation]
```

in my iOS app.

I believe `MKLocationManager` is a private class, and there does not seem to have a MapKit/MKLocationManager.h file.

I'm not targeting App Store. It's there any way I can use that private API?

**Update at 2011-6-23**

I really need the answer, or could I de-complie the iOS SDK?

100 reputation is almost all I have. Please help me.

Comment: @WTP, I think class-dump is some sort of decompile tool, right? I'll check it out, may be I only generate declarations of classes, will that work?

Comment: Indeed, it will only generate the interfaces, protocols and categories.

Comment: @WTP, what can I do with it then? I don't know how can I solve this problem.

Comment: @WTP, I have dumped all declarations of MapKit, but I still have no idea what I can do with it..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the above answer isn't working for you, this may be because the entire class is private (including it's header). Here's an alternative approach using some runtime trickery; you must be sure that the signature is correct but we can use some defensive coding to avoid a crash.

First, unless you are calling this just once, I'd wrap up the code in a helper method:

```
// in some header file, you may want to give the method a prefix too
CLLocation *ApplyLocationManagerChinaLocationShift(CLLocation *newLocation);
```

You can now use `NSClassFromString` to obtain a reference to the class and `performSelector` to perform the method. We can try and make sure the method exists first to be on the safe side:

```
CLLocation *ApplyLocationManagerChinaLocationShift(CLLocation *newLocation)
{
  id sharedLocationManager = [NSClassFromString(@"MKLocationManager") performSelector:@selector(sharedLocationManager)];

  SEL theSelector = @selector(_applyChinaLocationShift:);

  // this will ensure sharedLocationManager is non-nil and responds appropriately
  if (![sharedLocationManager respondsToSelector:theSelector]) {
    return nil; // fail silently - check this in the caller
  }
  return [sharedLocationManager performSelector:theSelector withObject:newLocation];
}
```

I haven't run the above code but it should do the trick. If for some reason the `@selector()` calls do not work (I think they should), then you can replace them with `NSSelectorFromString()` calls instead.

Comment: The code works, but it seems that _applyChinaLocationShift: can only be used for locations returned by CLLocationManager. It returns nil for arbitrary locations.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create the method description yourself, essentially creating your own category on MKLocationManager. By defining how the private method looks you make it callable. But you must be certain about it's signature, because if you are off then your app will just crash.

This category could be put in it's own .h file or if you only use it in one place right above the @implementation.

```
@interface MKLocationManager (china)
- (CLLocation *)_applyChinaLocationShift:(CLLocation *)newLocation;
@end
```

Comment: so I right a declaration of `MKLocationManager` class and `_applyChinaLocationShift:` method, and gcc will use implementation in the SDK?

Comment: I got an compile error: cannot find interface declaration for 'MKLocationManager'. I have `#import "MapKit/MapKit.h" 
#import "CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h"`. The biggest problem for me is I don't know which .h is `MKLocationManager` declared.

Comment: the signature should be `- (CLLocation *)_applyChinaLocationShift:(CLLocation *)newLocation;`