# How to find the inverse of the China transform in MKMapView?

Tags: ios

It seems to be a [known fact](http://home.wangjianshuo.com/archives/20081109_all_maps_in_china_are_transformed.htm) that `MKMapView` (and Google's maps in general) have a varying offset on 100-600m which makes annotations display incorrectly on the map.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401593/how-to-use-mklocationmanager-a-private-api-in-ios), Google has a private method called `_applyChinaLocationShift`, and it works, but apparently only for `CLLocations` that are given by `CLLocationManager`. For arbitrary `CLLocations`, it returns nil. The app I'm writing only needs to work in one city, so I've thought of pre-sampling the area using `_applyChinaLocationShift` and store the inverse transforms in the shipped app if that was possible.

So basically, is there any way to convert a coordinate to a coordinate that corresponds to the transformed China maps?

Comment: It's said that there's some formula or database to transform "Mars coordinates" to real ones, but I never got any of them working. Later I turned into an Chinese local map provider. I can't really use your way as I need coordinate of the entire country. This (force map providers to add offset to coordinates) is one good example of how silly this government could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using location simulation in the Simulator and feeding it a bunch of coordinates in that particular city.

Comment: That's clever. I'll try, and get back.