# Is one CLlocation2D uniquely coresponding to one place on Earth, regardless of map provider?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have this problem. I have an MKMapView and from NSLog I can see the coordinates (latitude 30.238685 and longitude 120.145461) of a place. then I put an annotation on it. 
At first,the annotation is at the place i want, centered on an island.

a-------------------------------

a------+++++++++++--------

a------++++PIN++++--------

a------+++++++++++--------

a--------------------------------

then I connect some VPN. then the map provider changed. there is a bit different in terms of color, and "legal" information.

but the position of annotation changed, abit south and east from the island. then I looked up the center of the island using NSlog, it gives me another latitude (30.241080) and longitude (120.140766).

a--------------after connecting VPN-----------------

a------+++++++++++-------------

a------+++++++++++---------------

a------+++++++++++--------PIN----

a------------------------------------

I want to make sure the annotation is at the center of the island all the time.
how do i solve this issue?

..sorry, i cannot post any pictures yet..

Comment: See this regarding map coordinates issue in China: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511588/how-to-deal-with-inconsistent-chinese-maps-on-ios-6

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the CLLocation2D is unique because it is (lattitude, longitude) couple on Earth, that does not move depending on who provide the map.

What can change is more likely the content of the map, especially on small island for instance. New-York will surely always be on the same place.

Try to put your Pin on a well-known place to see if it moves depending on map provider.